# Undefined offset: 1 after exploding "/"

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, explode

I have problem with exploding. i want to insert data and i use explode because the value is connected by slash "/". im using ajax to pass the value. here is my code:

Ajax in view :

```
var changeData = function(strData,intKode,dataToChange){
var noinvoice = $("input[name='noinvoice']").val();
var arrayData = {newData: strData, kode: intKode, invoice: noinvoice};
var kodepekerjaan = $("input[name='kodepekerjaan']").val();
var tab;
if (dataToChange=="qty_komponen"){
    tab = "tab2";
} else {
    tab = "tab1";
}
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('workorder/changedata');?>/"+dataToChange, 
    type: 'POST', 
    data: arrayData, 
    success: function(){
        location.reload();
    },
    error : function(data){
      var noinvoice = $("input[name='noinvoice']").val();
      alert(noinvoice);
      console.log(arrayData);
    }
});
```

Here is a console log and value shows correctly, i want explode the "kode" one which have "/" as a separator.

```
Object {newData: "2", kode: "FG-00044/OM1017", invoice: "PJ201603100001"}
```

And here is my query in model :

```
function edit_workorderkomponen($dataToChange){
    $kode = explode("/", $this->input->post('kode'));
    $noinvoice = $this->input->post('invoice');
    switch ($dataToChange){
        case 'qty_komponen' : 
            $qty = $this->input->post("newData");
            $q = "update itemworkorder set qty='".$qty."' where kodepekerjaan='".$kode[0]."' and kodebahan='".$kode[1]."' and noinvoice='".$noinvoice."'";
            break;
    }
    $this->db->query($q);
}
```

What makes it wrong? any help will be appreciated, sorry for my bad english. Thanks

Comment: can you dump `$kode` and `$this->input->post('kode')`

Comment: @VasilShaddix how to do that in ajax post? i try to dump but the result is `array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }` for `$kode` and `bool(false)` for `$this->input->post('kode')`

Comment: Is that object posted as JSON? Does CI automatically understand and decode JSON? Or will you have to `json_decode` the entire POST body yourself...?

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to escape the / character, like this: `$kode = explode("\/", $this->input->post('kode'));`

Comment: If I'm wrong just say so.  Please explain the down vote.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was thinking of javascript.